# Server crash and strange activity

Tags: debian, tor

I have a Yunohost server, and some days ago, I lost the connection.
The computer was off and I restart it and try to connect with SSH, but received below message :

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ED25519 key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:[REDACTED].
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ED25519 key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:3
  remove with:
  ssh-keygen -f "/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "serv.org"
ED25519 host key for serv.org has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

I solved the problem, connected to it, and tried to understand what happened.

The fact is I don't really have knowledge about crash investigation but on syslog I have some knowledge.

```
postfix/smtpd[11920]: connect from unknown[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]
```

with different IP (German and Chinese IP, associated with .torservers.net)

and a lot of other line related to tor

```
postfix/submission/smtpd[11938]: warning: hostname XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.torservers.net does not resolve to address 185.220.102.244: Name or service not known
```

I didn't  run any tor nodes.

Some idea of what could happen? Where to investigate? Is my server compromised ?

Comment: I would consider it compromised.

Comment: To be clear: The postfix log lines are irrelevant, you get them all the time. But a changed host key is a clear red flag that something is amiss. You didn't elaborate on the `strange activity`, so there is no way to say more.

Comment: For my point of view, that was the "strange activity"
I don't have the good habits about have a server, didn't know that there are this kind of line all the time (for me, it was a connection on my server)
So I have to do more investigation